# Is it possible to train a Google Home to recognize a certain invocation?

Tags: actions-on-google, invocation, dialogflow-es

I'm developing an application using the [Google Home](https://store.google.com/product/google_home). Although I'm using the [simulator](https://console.actions.google.com/) for most of my testing, occasionally I'd like to test using a real device.

Currently, my device has a really hard time recognizing my invocation phrase; I can see in [Google Home](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app&hl=en_GB)'s history that it is often misinterpreted by Google's NLP. This makes my application very difficult to run! Is it possible to re-train these certain phrases, so that it recognizes me better next time?

I've seen that it is possible to configure multiple invocation phrases in the *Draft* view on my [DialogFlow](https://console.dialogflow.com) project, using [Actions on Google](https://console.actions.google.com). I've tried to define slightly simpler phrases to ease invocation, but these are never recognized, not even by the simulator! It only ever accepts the default, difficult to pronounce expression.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I cant comment yet,(stackoverflow rules) so consider this as half answer:

If you tried to setup slightly simpler phrases and they are not recognized by the simulator than usually the invocation phrases are not correct setup. At least if you typed them as text into the simulator.

But I have to say I just tried to add other phrases via the "Additional triggering intents" at dialogflows Google Assitant Integrations and it didnt work. Soo... I dont know how to do that correct.

At all if you have problems with it Dialogflow recognize your phrase than you usually can add alternatives, that are more based on the words google actually understands when you said your phrase.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your advice. Where do you submit alternatives?

Comment: i tried it at dialogflow under Integrations => Google Assistant => Additional Triggering intents. I am just not 100% sure if this is the current place. I know its possible somewhere but that doesnt work for me. But maybe only because i did some other fault. If you use an action json so not only Dialogflow than just add additional trigger query pattern at the welcome intent: `trigger": {
          "queryPatterns": [
            "open cloud fleet manager",
            "open c f m"
          ]
        }`

Comment: It's really weird, I've found that if I make my voice really monotone and constant amplitude, it now detects the phrase every time. Strange!

Comment: I guess it translate voice into text and dont bias the speech model to much. So for special words it doesnt no from dictonary it have problems. Probable you can really improve it by using a more phonetic approach as trigger intent. Or add spaces where word parts usually are slow spoken or syllables.